# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () Spring boot with JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, token

[image]

Hi, I am creating Spring boot project with Jwt security to generate token for a user.
But i have error
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Aug 20 10:02:00 EEST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

The project structure is in the picture.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.esdt</groupId>
    <artifactId>delivery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>delivery</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

User Service

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<user> listAll(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(user user){
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public user get(UUID id){return  userRepository.findById(id).get();}

    public void delete(UUID id){
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if ("delivery".equals(username)) {
            return new User("delivery", "$2a$10$slYQmyNdGzTn7ZLBXBChFOC9f6kFjAqPhccnP6DxlWXx2lPk1C3G6",
                    new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
    }
}
```

User Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<user, UUID> {
        
        }
```

User Entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class user implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5926468583005150707L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID userId;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Integer phoneNumber;
    private UUID countryId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private UUID tenantId;
    private String token;


    public user() {
    }

    public user(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UUID getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(UUID userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(Integer phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public UUID getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(UUID countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public UUID getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(UUID tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

Jwt Response:

```
public class JwtResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8091879091924046844L;
    private final String jwttoken;

    public JwtResponse(String jwttoken) {
        this.jwttoken = jwttoken;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return this.jwttoken;
    }
}
```

User Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userDetailsService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<user> list(){

        return userService.listAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<user> get(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        try {
            user customer = userService.get(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<user>(customer, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<user>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public void add(@RequestBody user user) {
        userService.save(user);
    }

    @PutMapping("/user/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody user user,
                                    @PathVariable UUID id) {
        try {
            user existuser = userService.get(id);
            userService.save(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<user>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<user>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        userService.delete(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody user authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
    }
```

User Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class DeliveryCoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DeliveryCoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Config:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7858869558953243875L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}


public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
// JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
// only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

// Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

// if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
// authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
// After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
// that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
// Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}

@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L;
    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 5 * 60 * 60;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    //retrieve username from jwt token
    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    //retrieve expiration date from jwt token
    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {

        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);

    }

    //for retrieveing any information from token we will need the secret key

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {

        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

    }

   //check if the token has expired

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    //generate token for user

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    //while creating the token -
    //1. Define  claims of the token, like Issuer, Expiration, Subject, and the ID
    //2. Sign the JWT using the HS512 algorithm and secret key.
    //3. According to JWS Compact Serialization(https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41#section-3.1)
    //compaction of the JWT to a URL-safe string

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
    }

    //validate token

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
// configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
// user for matching credentials
// Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
// We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
// dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
// all other requests need to be authenticated
        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
// make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
// store user's state.
        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

// Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: the project is in the description. Your url isn't, neither is the code. What exactly do you expect us to do?

Comment: Okay, check the update

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP method you use (POST,PUT etc) matches the request you send, I suggest using a Postman like tool, debug createAuthenticationToken method in the controller and also doFilterInternal in JWT filter class. I can exactly say what's going on but this is a guide to narrow down the issue

Comment: @Marwa did this work? If yes you can accept it so you can increase the chances to get you more answers